# Updating Jenkin server from Java8 to Java 11 supports both Java8 and Java11 applications?

Tags: maven, jenkins, java-8, java-11

Currently my Jenkins server is using Java 8 version and its Maven version is 3.5.2. And we can build and package Java8 Spring-boot applications on it. To support Java11 spring-boot applications, trying to understand what is needed.
Does Jenkins server upgrade from Java8 to Java11 supports both Java8 and Java11 applications without any issues?
Should the Maven version also be upgraded?
Should I install Java11 on Jenkins Server without removing Java8 and first test if Java8 and Java11 works using Java11 tool and then slowly remove Java8?

Comment: Just because Jenkins runs with a given JDK doesn't mean that all (or even any) of its builds have to run with the same JDK. You can configure which JDKs Jenkin uses for running project builds on a per-project basis.

Comment: Install the needed JDK via global tools configuration and define in your appropriate job... via pipeline or alike..

Comment: No, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75184742/685806