# Does Jenkins continue support Java1.8?

Tags: jenkins

I was seeing notification in Jenkins regarding upgrading the Java version from 8 to 11 for future Jenkins release support. But I am not seeing that notification now. So little confused whether Jenkins continuing support with Java 1.8?[I was getting the java support notification to stop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iyNV.png)

Comment: You need to distinguish between **running** Jenkins, and **building** something **on** Jenkins. The former probably not, the latter likely yes (and otherwise you can target a lower Java version with `--release`).

Answer (score 1):

The comment by Mark Rotteveel is very important: running Jenkins with Java 11 is not a big deal, the problem is what you can build.  The biggest limitation is with Maven Jobs: if you have Maven projects based on Java 8 and you use Jenkins' Maven Job for them, you'll have to change something.
See https://plugins.jenkins.io/maven-plugin/ where it says:

> - Jenkins >= 1.520 requires Java 6 thus Maven jobs must be launched    with Java >= 6.
> - Jenkins >= 1.612 requires Java 7 thus Maven jobs must    be launched with Java >= 7.
> - Jenkins >= 2.54 requires Java 8 thus    Maven jobs must be launched with Java >= 8.
> - Jenkins >= 2.357 requires    Java 11 thus Maven jobs must be launched with Java >= 11.

The same thing is said at https://community.jenkins.io/t/maven-builds-fails-after-upgrade/3850/2.

Note that the migration guide at https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.361/ does not make evident this limitation: it says you can still use Java 8 to build your projects but it does not say that you cannot build them as Maven Jobs anymore.

Similarly [this post](https://community.jenkins.io/t/docker-plugin-how-to-create-build-image-still-providing-jdk8-with-jenkins-2-361-1/3933/2) says:

> The controller and agent must run java 11. [...] Your jobs however can
> run whatever they want.

But, again, this is true only if you opt out of Maven Jobs.  An alternative is to run the Maven Job with Java 11 but targeting a lower Java version with `--release` (which is not ideal IMHO).

Comment: I switched from a **Maven** to a **FreeStyle** job using the **Invoke top-level Maven targets** build step. This was using JDK 17 for Jenkins controller and agent, and JDK 8 for the Freestyle job. This worked for me, as mentioned above with Maven job I could not use a separate JDK for the build and the remoting.jar to connect to the agent.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Jenkins documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/#running-jenkins).

> Java 8 or Java 11 are required for running modern versions of Jenkins.
> Upgrading an existing Jenkins setup from Java 8 to Java 11? See the
> upgrade guidelines.
>
> Java 11 Docker installation instructions are included in "Downloading
> and running Jenkins in Docker"
>
> Starting with the Jenkins 2.357 weekly release, Java 11 or Java 17
> will be required. Java 8 is supported on the Long Term Support release
> line until the September 2022 LTS release.
>
> Java 17 users can run the jenkins/jenkins:jdk17 Docker image.
>
> All other Java versions are not supported.
>
> These requirements apply to all components of the Jenkins system,
> including Jenkins controller, all types of agents, CLI clients, and
> other components.
>
> Jenkins project performs a full test flow with the following JDK/JREs:
>
> OpenJDK JDK / JRE 11 - 64 bits
>
> OpenJDK JDK / JRE 17 - 64 bits
>
> JRE/JDKs from other vendors are supported and may be used. See our
> Issue tracker for known Java compatibility issues.